# Dos window show up then disappears immidiately

Tags: c++, cmd, createprocess

When I run the codes below, dos window show up immidiately then disappear.
What I want is the window will stay and wait for user's next command input.
What should i do with startupInfo.hStdInput if I want to keep window showing and I have to use createProcess in my project not the winexec etc.

```
int WINAPI WinMain(
                   HINSTANCE hInstance,
                   HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                   LPSTR lpComLine,
                   int nCmdShow)
{
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttr; 
    HANDLE hRead,hWrite;

secAttr.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES); 
secAttr.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL; 
secAttr.bInheritHandle = TRUE; 
if (!CreatePipe(&hRead,&hWrite,&secAttr,0)) 
{ 
    return FALSE; 
} 

char command[1024];
strcpy(command,"ping 192.168.0.1");

STARTUPINFO startupInfo;
PROCESS_INFORMATION processInfo; 
startupInfo.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO); 
GetStartupInfo(&startupInfo); 
startupInfo.hStdError = hWrite;     
startupInfo.hStdOutput = hWrite;
startupInfo.hStdInput = hRead;          
startupInfo.lpTitle = "CMD";

if (!CreateProcess(NULL, command,NULL,NULL,TRUE,NULL,NULL,NULL,&startupInfo,&processInfo)) 
{ 
        MessageBox(NULL, "Failed", NULL, MB_OK);
        CloseHandle(hWrite); 
        CloseHandle(hRead); 
        return FALSE; 
} 

CloseHandle(hWrite); 
CloseHandle(hRead);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you manually running `ping` like this at all, instead of using [`IcmpSendEcho()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366050.aspx)?

Comment: I am writing a project which I want to continuous input/output with console via my win32 application, so I expect dos window keep open after code CreateProcess(NULL, command,NULL,NULL,TRUE,NULL,NULL,NULL,&startupInfo,&processInfo) being executed and wait for the next user's command

Comment: The DOS window closes when the specified `command` finishes running. Since your `command` is just `ping` by itself, the DOS window will close when `ping` exits. If you want to keep the DOS window open after `ping` exits, you need to run `cmd.exe` instead with the `/K` command-line switch specified, and `ping` as the initial command for `cmd.exe` to execute, eg: `cmd.exe /K ping 192.168.0.1`. Use the `%COMSPEC%` environment variable to get the full path to `cmd.exe`.

Comment: Ty sir! But how do I input my commond line to cmd.exe? In this case 'code WriteFile(hRead, buffer, 1024, &bytesRead, NULL)' didn't do anything

Comment: I told you how. Set your `command` string to `"cmd /K ping 192.168.0.1"` and pass that whole string to `CreateProcess()`.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is that the process window closes immediately, may be you should add `pause` ... to be able to see the results of your `ping` command..

Now, I am in no way `c++` expert ... but I would suggest, to try something along  the following lines of code...

```
CreateProcess(  
                      "c:\\windows\\system32\\cmd.exe",  
                      "/k ping 192.168.0.1 && pause && exit",  
                      NULL,  
                      NULL,  
                      FALSE,  
                      0,  
                      NULL,  
                      NULL,  
                      &startupInfo,&processInfo);
```

Comment: Why would you use `&& pause && exit` with the the `/k` switch? The OP said to "*wait for user's next command input*", but this combo would not allow more user commands to be entered. Using `/k` by itself would. If you are just going to exit, you may as well drop `&& exit` and use `/c` instead of `/k`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau you are probably right ... I kind of missed the "next command" part...